# Why can't I mutate an NSObject allocated as mutable, referenced as immutable, then cast back to mutable?

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsobject, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm allocating an NSMutableAttributedString, then assigning it to the attributedString property of an SKLabelNode. That property is an (NSAttributedString *), but I figured that I could cast it to an (NSMutableAttributedString *) since it was allocated as such. And then access its mutableString property, update it, and not have to do another allocation every time I want to change the string.

But after the cast, the object is immutable and an exception is thrown when I try to mutate it.

Is it true that I can't mutate an NSObject that was allocated as mutable just because it was referenced as immutable?

Comment: *but I figured that I could cast it to an `(NSMutableAttributedString *)`*. No, you can't. Assigning an immutable object to a property declared as mutable changes the type to immutable.

Comment: @vadian: Thanks for the answer. Unless I misunderstand, I assume you meant to say "Assigning a **mutable** object to a property declared as **immutable** changes the type to immutable." Is that still a correct statement?

Comment: Oh, my bad, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it true that I can't mutate an NSObject that was allocated as mutable just because it was referenced as immutable?

No, your general intuition here is correct. Ignoring for a second the concept of "mutable" and "immutable" in general, but focusing on the *subclassing* relationship between `NS<SomeType>` and `NSMutable<SomeType>`: *typically*, Apple framework objects which have mutable/immutable counterparts have the *mutable* variant as a *subtype* of the immutable variant. Assigning a *mutable* variable to an *immutable* variable does not change anything about the stored variable, same as the following does not:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject @end
@implementation Foo @end

@interface Bar: Foo @end
@implementation Bar @end

Foo *f = [[Bar alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", f); // => <Bar: 0x6000014b0040>
```

You can see something similar with `NSMutableAttributedString` (though it's a little more complicated because `NSAttributedString` and subtypes form a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html):

```
NSAttributedString *s = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
NSLog(@"%@", [s class]); // => NSConcreteMutableAttributedString
```

**However:** the key difference between assigning to a *local* variable like with `f` and `s` above, and assigning to an `SKLabelNode`'s [`attributedText`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sklabelnode/2865816-attributedtext?language=objc) property lies in the property's definition:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy, nullable) NSAttributedString *attributedText;
```

Specifically, `SKLabelNode` performs a *copy* on assignment to its `attributedText` property, and performing a copy on an `NSMutableAttributedString` produces an *immutable* variant:

```
NSAttributedString *s = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"] copy];
NSLog(@"%@", [s class]); // => NSConcreteAttributedString
```

So, when you assign to your `SKLabelNode` in this way, it doesn't store your original instance, but a copy of its own — and it happens to be that this copy is immutable.

---

Note that this is behavior is a confluence of two things:

1. `SKLabelNode` *chooses* to `-copy` the assigned variable; if it `-retain`ed it instead (e.g. `@property(nonatomic, strong, nullable)`), this would work as you expected
2. `NSMutableAttributedString` returns an `NSAttributedString` from its `-copy` method, but it doesn't *have* to. In fact, most types return `instancetype` from `-copy`, but `NSMutableAttributedString` *chooses* to return an `NSAttributedString` from its `-copy` method. (Well, that is the point of the class cluster: `-copy` → immutable, `-mutableCopy` → mutable)

So in general, this need not be the case, but you will see this behavior for mutable/immutable class clusters which are implemented using these rules.

For comparison, with the `Foo` example above:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject @end
@implementation Foo
- (instancetype)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    // Expects to return a new Foo:
    return [[[self class] alloc] init];

    // OR:
    // Not all types allow copying:
    return self;
}
@end

@interface Bar: Foo @end
@implementation Bar @end

Foo *f = [[[Bar alloc] init] copy];
NSLog(@"%@", f); // => <Bar: 0x600001e7c1a0>
```

Comment: That was a spectacular answer. Thank you!

Comment: @eglynum Happy to have helped! :)